# Testing javascript with rspec and capybara gives me a timeout error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to test a page which uses Javascript to do an ajax call.

I can see that the action in my controller is being called correctly and that a 200 is send back to the html page. But somehow, in javascript, the error function is triggered instead of the success function... Javascript is working fine, but it's like it doens't wait for an answer from the server... The answer from the server is sent back in a matter of milliseconds.

I'm not using a database in rails.

I commented out `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true`

And in my configuration I added following:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

Using latest rails version, latest Capybara version and latest rspec version...

It's hard to debug the problem as I don't know what's really going on behind the scenes. I think it has something to do with a timeout problem, but I'm not sure.

By the way, my javascript looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    dataType:'json',
    url:url,
    data:data,
    silent:true,
    loader:$("input#x, input#y").next(".loader"),
    success:function (response) {
        ...
    },
    error:function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        redirectToLoginPage(jqXHR.status);
    }
});
```

Could anybody point me to an example of rspec & capybara doing an Ajax call?

Comment: Your title says you're getting a time out error, but your post says that the error portion of your AJAX call is being triggered, which is a valid thing that wouldn't cause a time out error. So, which is happening? Also, try doing the exact steps of your test in your browser/console, just for sanity. Other than that, I'd recommend that after you do whatever action fires the AJAX, wait for the AJAX: http://pivotallabs.com/users/mgehard/blog/articles/1671-waiting-for-jquery-ajax-calls-to-finish-in-cucumber (I know the link is for Cucumber, but same idea).

Comment: In my browser everything works fine. The error portion is being triggered saying a timeout occurred. Sorry for it being so unclear, but it's hard to explain something so strange... Anyway, changed from chrome to firefox and now it is working fine...

Comment: Apparently using firefox works fine because the javascript isn't even executed...

Comment: Could anybody point me to an example of rspec & capybara doing an Ajax call?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
```

For one of the available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium, :webkit, :webkit_debug

For example:

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :selenium
```

Comment: Two years later, moving from :chrome to :selenium solved an irregular ajax failure for me, but I don't know why.